# Scroll disable with content re-sizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I created a responsive page using HTML and CSS with some screens(including video) viewing by vertical scroll. But on specific window size "960x540", video is not visible completely. I have to scroll down for viewing video.

So I want, if window resize then all content can be adjust according to it without vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Maybe that is your breakpoint and that is why your CSS isn't applying. 
How are you defining your viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Better to put your video as responsive. Like -

CSS:

```
video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src="my_movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```